# Android hierarchical ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to implement a simple tree-like menu. I have a `ListView` as the root. Each item is a custom `View` that consists of an arrow icon at the right if it has a submenu and a checkbox taking up the rest of the row. This is all great.

Now here is what I want to do and can't figure out how (I am new to Android, but Googling didn't help me):
If the user slides to the left on an item with an arrow, the whole list will slide out to the left and the corresponding submenu will slide in from the right. If the user slides to the right anywhere on the menu, the whole menu will slide out to the right and the parent menu will slide back in from the left. When you picture it it is really a simple concept.

My problem seems to be double:

1. I can't figure out how to capture a sliding motion. I assume there is some onSlide event or some such, but I can't find it.
2. I can't seem to attach events to the individual items. I tried just a simple toast with the onItemClickListener and couldn't get it to fire.

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the Sliding, check out the `ViewPager` class and the matching Adapter class, but generally what you describe sounds a lot like iOS and you should rather not try to duplicate a behaviour that's alien to Android users.

Comment: I am not familiar with iOS or Android. How would you implement a tree-structure selection in android? Something like a filesystem browser, where you can select files or whole folders to perform some operation on.

Comment: Sorry, but your description sounded a lot like the iOS list/sublist pattern. I don't say you cannot use it, but it it's not common. For information about how to make things in Android, have a look at http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/. If you're especially interested in how Filemanagers work, the best way is to have a look at existing Filemanager Apps like  OI File Manager (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.filemanager)